# C# Matrix*Vector = DotProduct Using MathNet Library

Tags: c#, neural-network, matrix-multiplication, mathnet-numerics

I am currently building a FeedForward Neural Network library on C# and am struggling with matrix multiplication.

To those who are familiar with MathNet library; is there an existing function where it can take a Matrix and Vector (or versa) and return a Scalar as dot product?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there doesn't seem to be an existing function for it. You can use the following:

```
double dotproduct = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= m.ColumnCount; i++) {
    dotproduct += m.Column(i).DotProduct(v);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that function isn't part of the Matrix<T> class.

Comment: Are you trying to do a dot product between a matrix and a vector?

Comment: Yes, Joseph. TIA

Comment: Is this what you want? `var dotproduct = m.Multiply(v)`

Comment: Nope. That returns another matrix. I was wondering if the library has a Matrix - Vector multiplication that returns their dot product (a scalar value).

Comment: Is the scalar result you are after just the sum of the all the entries of the multiplication? Otherwise, please refer me to a link which explains the mathematical operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: Yes, sir. Or this: http://arrayfire.org/docs/matrix_vector_dot_product.png However, I've searched the MathNet lib and it's not in there. So I might as well just create a function as an extension.

Comment: Ok, now i know what you mean. Please see my edit hopefully it will help you (if it's correct!)

Comment: Thank you, Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to dot product two vectors in MathNet (was not able to figure out how to do it with a matrix)

Install MathNet.Spatial nuget

```
using MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean;
```

---

Then...

[image]

The `Vector3D` struct comes from the spatial ecluidian namespace

Answer (score 0):

the * operator between two vector objects in mathnet.numerics is their dot product.

Also, if you multiply an mxn matrix with a vector of length n, you get the scalar dot product results of each row of the matrix with the vector in the as a vector in the output.